# Spring security LDAP WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

Since WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was deprecated in 5.7 I've got a question how to replace old config

Old config:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter(usersFilter)
            .contextSource()
            .url(url)
            .managerDn("login")
            .managerPassword("password");
    }                                                                       
}
```

In [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) not said how to replace .url(), .managerDn() and .managerPassword()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource defaultSpringSecurityContextSource() {

    var contextSourceFromProviderUrl = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(url);
    contextSourceFromProviderUrl.setUserDn("login");
    contextSourceFromProviderUrl.setPassword("password");

    return contextSourceFromProviderUrl;
}

@Bean
AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource defaultSpringSecurityContextSource) {

    var factory = new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(defaultSpringSecurityContextSource);
    factory.setUserSearchFilter(usersFilter);

    return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it asks me to fill dn patterns beacause I doesnt have the searchfilter, so: factory.setUserDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern);